# When I add my favicon link it wont show it it just shows as the globe one

Tags: html, css, favicon

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="V5oQVDkc0RXULBgfYG1Gt7O3nUw_cqbZ-mgRTyBS0VA" />
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" id="wixDesktopViewport" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<base href="https://stephenfaulkner080.wixsite.com/website-1/">
<meta name="generator" content="Wix.com Website Builder"/>

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"> 
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<!-- Safari Pinned Tab Icon -->
```

so basically its from <link rel="apple-touch-icon to <meta name+"theme-color

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

Make sure the favicon.ico is at the root of your site. Alternatively you can let a [reputable html/icon generator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) do the work.